# Is there a Rails plugin to help me build an API for ember-data's RESTAdapter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rest, ember-data

So I'm going to embark on a project using ember-data, which tells me

> The REST adapter assumes that the URLs and JSON associated with each model are conventional; this means that, if you follow the rules, you will not need to configure the adapter or write any code in order to get started.

Right-o! I want to do that. But what I would like to know is: **is there a gem out there to help me build this REST API**? If so, I could save time and use it instead of reinventing the wheel myself (and misinterpreting the conventions). Alternatively, I could set about developing such a framework as a separate gem!

So far I've seen

- https://github.com/emberjs/ember-rails (seems focused on managing the javascript side and asset pipeline)
- https://github.com/dgeb/ember_data_example  (more an example app than a framework?)

and neither of them appear to be quite what I'm after. Am I wrong here?

(N.B. please consider me aware of the experimental nature of ember-data and the implications associated with it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it but this might be what you want: https://github.com/hedtek/ember-generators

If you're referring to the rails backend look at [active model serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) (which I believe is a dependency with the ember-rails gem). And then for your controllers use `respond_to :json` and in your actions do `respond_with <your_active_record_model_or_array_of_models>`. Hope that helps.